when a variable has no value initialised in local scope it seaches value global scope
#include<stdio.h>
static int i=27;
int main()
{
  static int i;
  printf("%d",i);
}

The output of this program is 0 as the local scope has auto initialized 0 as i empty but should'nt it be 27 as i is been initialised as 27 in global scope.

Why would it be? The local variable shadows the global variable and is completely independent of it.

No, it shouldn't. The local variable shadows the global variable.

BTW, the output could be anything. Local variables are not automatically initialized to 0.

Whether a variable is initialised does not affect its scope.

@Barmar — The static int i; inside main() is implicitly initialized to zero.  If it was an automatic variable, it would not have a defined initializer.

@Barmar: According to §6.7.9 ¶10 of the ISO C11 standard, local variables with static storage duration are initialized to zero, unless they are initialized explicitly to something else.

@AndreasWenzel I didn't notice that it was declared static.

The global variable i and the local variable i in the function main are not the same variable, even if they have the same name.
When you write
printf("%d",i);

you are referring to the variable i in the innermost scope, which is the local variable, not the global variable. In this case, one variable is said to "shadow" the other variable.
The global variable is being explicitly initialized to 27.
The local variable is not being explicitly initialized, so it is being implicitly initialized to 0.
Usually, local variables have automatic storage duration. In that case, when they are not explicitly initialized to a specific value, they have an indeterminate value until a value is assigned to them. However, because the local variable i has been declared as static, it has static storage duration, not automatic storage duration. For this reason, it is implicitly initialized to 0 prior to program startup.


when a variable has no value initialised in local scope it seaches
value global scope

To get the output 27 as you suppose you need to change the storage class specifier static to extern in the declaration of the variable i within the function main
#include<stdio.h>
static int i=27;
int main()
{
  extern int i;
  printf("%d",i);
}

In this case the declaration of i in main (that is not at the same time its definition) will refer to the definition of the variable i declared before main.
Otherwise this declaration in main
  static int i;

defines a new block scope variable that hides the file scope variable with the same name. And as this variable has the storage class specifier static it is implicitly zero-initialized.
